# Add leading 0 in sed substitution

Tags: sed

I have input data:

```
foo 24
foobar 5 bar
bar foo 125
```

and I'd like to have output:

```
foo 024
foobar 005 bar
bar foo 125
```

So I can use this sed substitutions:

```
s,\([a-z ]\+\)\([0-9]\)\([a-z ]*\),\100\2\3,
s,\([a-z ]\+\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([a-z ]*\),\10\2\3,
```

But, can I make one substitution, that will do the same? Something like:

```
if (one digit) then two leading 0
elif (two digits) then one leading 0
```

Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt that the "if - else" logic can be incorporated in *one* substitution command without saving the intermediate data (length of the match for instance). It doesn't mean you can't do it easily, though. For instance:

```
$ N=5
$ sed -r ":r;s/\b[0-9]{1,$(($N-1))}\b/0&/g;tr" infile
foo 00024
foobar 00005 bar
bar foo 00125
```

It uses recursion, adding one zero to all numbers that are shorter than `$N` digits in a loop that ends when no more substitutions can be made. The `r` label basically says: try to do substitution, then `goto r` if found something to substitute. See more on flow control in `sed` [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-58).

Comment: @Artur I've added a brief explanation and a link, feel free to ask.

Comment: What about `12,345` and `123.45`?

Comment: @potong The example only has integer numbers, so I assume this regex is enough. You are right that the answer isn't applicable to your example, as each would be treated as two numbers instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

Use two substitute commands: the first one will search for one digit and will insert two zeroes just before, and the second one will search for a number with two digits and will insert one zero just before. `GNU sed` is needed because I use the word boundary command to search for digits (`\b`).

```
sed -e 's/\b[0-9]\b/00&/g; s/\b[0-9]\{2\}\b/0&/g' infile
```

---

**EDIT** to add a test:

Content of `infile`:

```
foo 24 9
foo 645 bar 5 bar
bar foo 125
```

Run previous command with following output:

```
foo 024 009
foo 645 bar 005 bar
bar foo 125
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the max number of leading zeros first, then take this number of characters from the end:

```
echo 55 | sed -e 's:^:0000000:' -e 's:0\+\(.\{8\}\)$:\1:'

00000055
```

Comment: cool, but I don't understand :D

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the `sed` options covered, here's one way with `awk`:

```awk
BEGIN      { RS="[ \n]"; ORS=OFS=""   }
/^[0-9]+$/ { $0 = sprintf("%03d", $0) } 
           { print $0, RT             }
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the following **sed** approach to pad an integer number with zeroes to 5 (n) digits quite straighforward:

```
sed -e "s/\<\([0-9]\{1,4\}\)\>/0000\1/; s/\<0*\([0-9]\{5\}\)\>/\1/"
```

1. If there is at least one, at most 4 (n-1) digits, add 4 (n-1) zeroes in
   front
2. If there is any number of zeroes followed by 5 (n) digits after the first transformation, keep just these last 5 (n) digits

When there happen to be more than 5 (n) digits, this approach behaves the usual way -- nothing is padded or trimmed.

Input:

```
0
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
```

Output:

```
00000
00001
00012
00123
01234
12345
123456
1234567
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
echo '1.23 12,345 1 12 123 1234 1' | 
sed 's/\(^\|\s\)\([0-9]\(\s\|$\)\)/\100\2/g;s/\(^\|\s\)\([0-9][0-9]\(\s\|$\)\)/\10\2/g' 
1.23 12,345 001 012 123 1234 001
```

or perhaps a little easier on the eye:

```
sed -r 's/(^|\s)([0-9](\s|$))/\100\2/g;s/(^|\s)([0-9][0-9](\s|$))/\10\2/g'
```