# Bash: zero pad arbitrary number of "numbers" in filename

Tags: bash, shell, rename

I have 100s of subdirectories with 100s of files each who's filename (may) have numbers that need to be zero-padded.

I have found solutions for padding 1 number in filenames of the form:

```
    file1.txt -> file001.txt
```

But my situation is little more complex.

But in my case:

- Filenames may have more than 1 number. All numbers must be padded.
- Filenames may contain spaces.
- Some filenames may not need any padding.

For example:

```
    "v10 file p1-2.txt"      -> "v010 file p001-002.txt"
    1.txt                    -> 001.txt
    "v011 file p001-002.txt" -> do nothing
    002.txt                  -> do nothing
```

So i need a "generic" bash loop to rename (if needed) all the files in the subdirectories with all its numbers zero padded but I am unsure of how to accomplish this.

I have not found any help on padding more that one number in a filename.

Thank you in advance.

Edit 1:

In reality, this is part of a larger script that does more processing, but as of now this is what I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ../test
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for file in ./*
do
    cd ${file}
    ls *
    # do something
    # mv "something" to ../../test
    cd ..
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

exit 0

The problem is that "do something" will not perform as intended if there are unpadded filenames (the result ends up with shuffled pages).

There are many solutions for the simple padding situation, right now I was looking at:

Solution form http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=2850

```
#!/bin/bash
# zeropad.sh
num=`expr match "$1" '[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*'`
paddednum=`printf "%03d" $num`
echo ${1/$num/$paddednum}
```

and then inserting this before "do something"

```
for i in *.*; do mv $i `./zeropad.sh $i`; done
```

But I am aware that this solution might not be perfect and might not be extended for my purpose.

Edit 2:

The solution to my problem was:

```
perl -pe 's{([^0-9]+)?([0-9]+)}{$1 . sprintf("%03s",$2)}ge'
```

Comment: Show us your solution for transforming `file1.txt` to `file001.txt`, we'll try to help you extend it to other forms.

Comment: Just a thought: this would probably be easier to do with less chance of mistakes in Ruby or Python etc.

Comment: I would be open to a solution in Python or Ruby. I am just not knowledgeable of these programming languages. I just said Bash because I thought it might be simple and I could later integrate it with the rest of the script.

Comment: Related `sed` question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12129382/1258041

Comment: @Lev LevitskyI have tried your suggestion, but the output it still not what is expected.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/\b(\d{1,2})\b/ sprintf("%03i", $1) /ge'`

Comment: @tripleee user@debian:~$ "v10 p14-15.jpg" | perl -pe 's/\b(\d{1,2})\b/ sprintf("%03i", $1) /ge'

v10 p14-015.jpg

Comment: @user3548276 `perl -pe 's{([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)}{$1 . sprintf("%03s",$2)}ge'` should work for you.

Comment: @devnull That almost solve it, but files like 15.jpg are not padded.

Comment: Add a `?` after the first group.  `perl -pe 's{([^0-9]+)?([0-9]+)}{$1 . sprintf("%03s",$2)}ge'`

Comment: Thank you! I keep telling myself I have to really work on studying regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the `sed` solution from the question I linked to your case can be done like this:

```
sed -r ':r;s/([^0-9]|^)([0-9]{1,2})([^0-9]|$)/\10\2\3/g;tr' file_list
v010 Cover.jpg
v010 End.jpg
v010 p000.jpg
v010 p010-011.jpg
v010 p012-013.jpg
v010 p014-015.jpg
v010 p016-017.jpg
v010 p018-019.jpg
v010 p019;TN.jpg
v010 p001.jpg
v010 p002-003.jpg
v010 p004-005.jpg
v010 p006-007.jpg
v010 p008-009.jpg
```