# Adding leading 0 in sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I would like to add leading zeros to a string of digits so as to have exactly three digits. Consider for example

```
echo "hello_1"   | sed -E 's/([0-9]+)/00\1/'  # hello_001
echo "hello_12"  | sed -E 's/([0-9]+)/0\1/'   # hello_012
echo "hello_123" | sed -E 's/([0-9]+)/\1/'    # hello_123
```

Now, the issue is that I am using three different expressions here while I get piped to `sed` several lines at one. Something like

```
printf "hello_1\nhello_12\nhello_123\n" | sed -E 's/([0-9]+)/0\1/'
hello_01
hello_012
hello_0123
```

The result is not the one I am looking for. The expected output is

```
hello_001
hello_012
hello_123
```

I tried

```
printf "hello_1\nhello_12\nhello_123\n" |  sed -r ":r;s/\b[0-9]{1,$((3-1))}\b/0&/g;tr"
hello_1
hello_12
hello_123
```

that I got from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129382/add-leading-0-in-sed-substitution) but it does not work and I don't understand how it works.

---

I am using `GNU sed version 4.2.1` on Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can consider `awk` then it is much easier using `printf`:

```
printf "hello_1\nhello_12\nhello_123\n" | awk -F_ '{printf "%s%s%03d\n", $1, FS, $2}'

hello_001
hello_012
hello_123
```

Comment: `awk` made it easy +1! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pad on the left with zeros to exactly 3 digits,
then you could use two regex replacements:

- Replace `_[0-9]$` with two zeros padded
- Replace `_[0-9][0-9]$` with one zero padded

Like this:

```
sed -E -e 's/_([0-9])$/_00\1/' -e 's/_([0-9][0-9])$/_0\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Why it's not working

The `sed` program you tried doesn't work for you because it anchors digits on a word boundary (`\b`) to the left and right, and **`_` is considered a word character** (word characters are letters, digits and the underscore). If you replace `_` with `-` (or whitespace), you'll see that it works:

```
$ printf "hello-1\nhello-12\nhello-123\n" | sed -E ':a; s/\b[0-9]{1,2}\b/0&/g; ta'
hello-001
hello-012
hello-123
```

#### General `sed` solution

To fix it for a general case (and also for your example input), you can **use a non-digit character `[^0-9]` instead of `\b`** on both left and right (combined with `^` and `$` to handle the beginning and ending of line):

```
$ printf "hello_1\nhello_12\nhello_123\n" | sed -E ':a; s/(^|[^0-9])([0-9]{1,2})([^0-9]|$)/\10\2\3/g; ta'
hello_001
hello_012
hello_123
```

This works similarly to the original expression: it recursively prepends digit zero to any isolated sequence of `1`-`2` digits. Branching command `t` loops to the beginning (label `:a`) as long as substitutes are made -- i.e. as long as there exists an isolated group of digits, shorter than `3` characters.

Capturing groups `\1` and `\3` are simply passing-thru the context around the digits captured in `\2`. We need them only for matching the group of isolated digits.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use perl:

```
printf "hello_1\nhello_12\nhello_123\n" | perl -ne 's/(\d{1,3})$/sprintf("%3.3d", $1)/e; print;' -
```

This looks for up to 3 digits at the end of the input line and changes that to 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses only `sed` and it's flexible if you wanted to support more than 3 zero-padded digits.

```
printf "hello_1\nhello_12\nhello_123\n" \
  | sed -e 's:_\([0-9]\):_00\1:;s:_0*\(...\):_\1:'
```

Here's what it looks like if you wanted 8 zero-padded digits using only `sed`.

```
printf "hello_1\nhello_12\nhello_123\n" \
  | sed -e 's:_\([0-9]\):_0000000000\1:;s:_0*\(........\):_\1:'
```

If it's not obvious, what's happening is - the original numeric portion is retained but several zeros are inserted before it.  After that happens, a second pattern keeps only the last N digits, swallowing the extra leading zeros.