# Using sed to convert IP address to company-standard DNS name?

Tags: sed, dns, ip-address, ipv4, string-substitution

I've got a COTS product that requires we set a certain configuration property with a DNS name, rather than an IP address.  Fortunately, our company standardized what the DNS names for that class of servers will look like.  For example, an IP of `10.2.100.50` would have a DNS name of `S010002100050.mycorp.com`.  That is, it takes each octet from the IP address, prepends enough 0's that the value has exactly 3 characters, and then appends the DNS suffix.  Simple, right?

My problem is, I need to take the IP address and convert it to the DNS name so I can apply it during my automated server config.  I'm not the most skilled at sed, but I thought it could be used to do this.  Unfortunately, I can't for the life of me figure out how.  I came across a couple of related Stackoverflow questions ([question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129382/add-leading-0-in-sed-substitution), [question 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/zero-fill-numbers-to-2-digits-with-sed)) that talked about pre-pending 0's, but try as I might I couldn't get it to work as expected.

Can anyone give some advice and guidance on how I can accomplish this??  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
ip="10.2.100.50"
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)/00\1/g; s/0*([0-9]{3})/\1/g; s/\.//g; s/(.*)/S\1.mycorp.com/' <<< "$ip"
```

Output:

```
S010002100050.mycorp.com
```

I had to divide the process into four steps:

- `s/([0-9]+)/00\1/g` prepends "00" to each octet.
- `s/0*([0-9]{3})/\1/g` extracts the last three digits out of each octet.
- `s/\.//g` removes the dots.
- `s/(.*)/S\1.mycorp.com/` appends the suffix.

Other language such as `perl` may do it with fewer steps.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks!